# How to use phpunit testing with local api

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, api-platform.com

I've got 2 docker containers, one with apiplatform and one with symfony which connecting to this api with docker container name, so my url in browser is different than url that connects containers.

```
url browser: http://apilocal/  
url container: http://api/
```

I can't use phpunit test, cause in my controller i use http://api/ and it isnt visible throught browser, so everytime it repsonse 500.

Is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: You need to share the same docker network between docker compose containers

Answer (score 0):

If your API responses with an error 500, you're app is not working propably. It should be possible to use phpunit following the [Symfony Testing Guidelines](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html).

In a test case which requests a endpoint, you should not use the whole URL with `http://api/endpoint`, but only the endpoint without the host part (`/endpoint`).

Bad way:

```
$client->request('GET', 'http://docker_container/profile');
```

Good way:

```
$client->request('GET', 'h/profile');
```

To test the connection between to services, it is a good practice to mock the other service as first step, and as a second step, you can use for example contract-testing. https://docs.pact.io/ is a good tool to do that.

The tests should run inside the Docker container(s).

Comment: Yeah right, but i want to test controller which fetch data from my api (which is in another docker container). I'm using ```$client->request('GET', '/profile');```in test, but it response 500, cause it need to get data from api, and calls ```docker_container``` inside that tested controller.

Comment: To test the connection between to services, it is a good practice to mock the other service as first step, and as a second step, you can use for example contract-testing. https://docs.pact.io/ is a good tool to do that.

Answer (score 0):

And if you use the public URL does it work ?
If so, I'd check if the two containers shares the same network. And if so I'd check the effective URL to be sure there's nothing append to the URL requested using:

```
$response->getEffectiveUrl();
```

Otherwise, I'd use the [mock handler](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#mock-handler) provided by guzzle to mock the HTTP response.

Comment: containers talk with each others, they are in the same network. The problem is in one controller that has symfony request to my api, and this request cant pass thru browser, so thats why i got 500. Is it possible to pass request from one container to another with public expose url?